# Book recommendation for differential and integral calculus of one and of several variables

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

I want to re-study  differential and integral calculus of one and of several variables and be able to solve all kinds of low to high level problems related to them. Iit has been 3-4 years I solved integral problems in high school and now I want to prepare for GRE math subject test whose 50% syllabus is

"*Material learned in the usual sequence of elementary calculus courses — differential and integral calculus of one and of several variables — including calculus-based applications and connections with coordinate geometry, trigonometry, differential equations and other branches of mathematics.*"

After googling for a while, I thought about going with these two classical books

[Differential Calculus-Byerly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BLOJH2U) and

[Integral calculus-Byerly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1112347100)

I could not find any reviews of this book. Is this a right choice, as I believe if I can make my concepts clear then any problem is easy. Or should I buy another modern texts, if so, please recommend.

Thanks!

Comment: For those who don't know about the GRE math subject test, here is a sample test: https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_math.pdf

Comment: When you say it's been a long time since you solved problems with integrals, do you mean you haven't been doing math since then and have forgotten it, or just that you haven't done many computational exercises on integrals? If it's the former, I would recommend *Calculus, Vols 1, 2* by Apostol. If it's the latter (and you already know analysis reasonably well), then it might be better to get a problem book than a textbook.

Answer (score 2):

I like **Kenneth Kuttler** - *Calculus: Theory and Applications*, since it starts from beginning and goes to advanced and cool stuff. Also there are all the proofs with much details! That is the book for serious students in mathematics and physics.

Don't waste your time with titles like "Calculus for morons".

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests that you want to learn calculus which stresses computations and problem-solving skills. For that, in my opinion, the textbooks by James Stewart would be excellent choices. The single-variable and multi-variable texts are both available on Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Theodore Shifrin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/71348/ted-shifrin)'s Multivariable Mathematics. It covers some important aspects of integration on Euclidean space and Linear algebra. Some basics about differential equations are also covered.

Comment: Great book but not sure it's the best choice for GRE prep.